# Exiting insert mode in Evil mode and saving immediately (Ctrl + [, :w) causes errors

Tags: evil

I've recently shifted to Emacs + Evil for my dev setup, and seem to be running into a rather strange issue with Emacs 24: when I exit Insert mode using Ctrl+[ and try to save the file with :w, Emacs enters the debugger with this error message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable w)                                    
eval(w nil)                                                                      
eval-expression(w nil)                                                           
call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)                                      
command-execute(eval-expression)
```

This does not happen if I pause for a few seconds after Ctrl+[. This also appears to be restricted only to Emacs in terminal - this happens quite frequently on bash/Cygwin, but never happens on the standalone version of Emacs

Does anyone know what could be going wrong? I have this configuration in my .emacs foe evil mode:

```
(setq evil-want-C-i-jump nil) 
(require 'evil) 
(evil-mode t)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this was just due to a TMUX setting (forgot to mention I'm always inside a tmux session), got it working with this setting (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312178/tmux-and-vim-escape-key-being-seen-as-and-having-long-delay/13843382#13843382)

```
set -s escape-time 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Emacs allows using the escape key in place of meta to support it in terminals.  To tell the sequence `ESC :` apart from `M-:`, you must either use the GUI or check the delay between them, if it's greater than a given threshold (as seen in `evil-esc-delay`), it's considered the former.  This is a somewhat fragile solution as it breaks apart when introducing extra layers, like a SSH session.  It's recommended to use the GUI at all times.

Comment: Thanks! It seems however the issue was due to a tmux issue, got it working by setting the escape time there (forgot to mention I was running in Tmux)

Comment: Well, that's one of the layers I was hinting at. Glad you managed to find the error source!